# How to adapt dictionary's values for reading in swift?

Tags: swift

#### Edited Question: How to adapt dictionary's values FOR READING in swift?

I want to adapt values of the dictionary for reading without changing of origin. I implemented the following class to do it.

```
class DictionaryView<Key, Value> where Key: Hashable {
   let origin: Dictionary<Key, Value>
   let map: (Value) -> Value
   
   init(_ origin: Dictionary<Key, Value>,
        map: @escaping (Value) -> Value) {
       self.origin = origin
       self.map = map
    }

   subscript(_ key: Key) -> Value?{
      let value = origin[key]
      return value == nil ? value : map(value!)
   }

}
```

But doesn't work as I expected. The following code

```
var origin = ["A":2, "B":3]
var adapted = DictionaryView(origin, map: { $0 * 2 })
origin["C"] = 6

print(origin)
print(adapted["A"])
print(adapted["B"])
print(adapted["C"])
```

gives me output:

> ["B": 3, "C": 6, "A": 2]
> Optional(4)
> Optional(6)
> nil

I need to have an adaptation that will print Optional(12) insted of nil.
How to do it?

---

#### Original Question: How to adapt dictionary's values in swift?

I have a dictionary `origin`

```
var origin = ["A":2, "B":3]
```

And want to create a new dictionary that will be based on `origin` but contained double values. My naïve solution was to map it by `mapValues`

```
var adapted = origin.mapValues { $0 * 2 }
```

But this solution creates a new transformed dictionary based on the moment of `origin`'s state. For example following code

```
origin["C"] = 6

print(origin)
print(adapted)
```

outputs

> ["A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 6]
> ["A": 2, "B": 4]

But I want to have true adaptation. I need a solution that will output the result as below for the code as above.

> ["A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 6]
> ["A": 2, "B": 4, "C": 12]

I am new in swift and have no deep knowledge of the standard library.
Before starting of bicycle design I'm asking: What will be a common solution to this problem in swift?

---

**Remark 1**

I found the problem in a real situation but created a simplified example to extract the essence of the problem (avoid noize of details) for the current question. But as I see the real situation is necessary to clear up the question.

I needed to implement the observable pattern and developed 4 parts of it in Observable.swift file.

Subscription:

```
struct Subscription {
    private let handler: () -> ()
    
    init(cancel handler: @escaping () -> ()) {
        self.handler = handler
    }
    
    func cancel() {
        handler()
    }
}
```

Observer:

```
struct Observer<Event> {
    private let handler: (Event) -> ()
    
    init(send handler: @escaping (Event) -> ()) {
        self.handler = handler
    }
    
    func send(_ event: Event) {
        handler(event)
    }
}
```

Observable:

```
class Observable<Event> {
    
    fileprivate var observers: [UUID : Observer<Event>] = [:]
    func subscribe(_ observer: Observer<Event>) -> Subscription {
        let id = UUID()
        observers[id] = observer
        return Subscription(cancel: { self.observers[id] = nil })
    }
}
```

Subject:

```
class Subject<Event> : Observable<Event> {
    private(set) lazy var observer = Observer<Event>(
        send: { event in
            for o in self.observers.values {
                o.send(event)
            }})
}
```

As a common, I provide a single instance of Subject as Observable outside client class and use as Observer inside to have good encapsulation. Example of use:

```
class Acc {
   private let numberAdded: Observer<Int> 
   let numberDidAdd: Observable<Int>
   
   init() {
     let subject = Subject<Int>()
     numberAdded = subject.observer
     numberDidAdd = subject
   }

   func add(_ number: Int) {
       numberAdded.send(number)
   }
}

let acc = Acc()
acc.numberDidAdd.subscribe(Observer<Int>(send: { print($0) }))
acc.add(4)
acc.add(5)
```

This solution is useful for me in the situation when I need a simple event. Problems started when I needed to implement more complex events subscribing interface. I needed to provide a dictionary of events (Observables outside, Observers inside). The following code is part of the real context. It isn't easy to describe this context, but I think it possible to catch it from code.

```
class RealClass {

    let buttonEvents = ButtonEvents()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for (event, observer) in buttonEvents.observers {
            someInternalSubscriptionFunc(event, observer)
        }
        
        buttonEvents.newEventTypeDidAdd.subscribe(
            Observer(send: { event in
                self.someInternalSubscriptionFunc(
                   event, self.buttonEvents.observers[event]!)
            })
    }

    public class ButtonEvents {
        
        private let newEventTypeAdding = Subject<UIControl.Event>()
        private(set) lazy var newEventTypeDidAdd
            : Observable<UIControl.Event> 
            = newEventsTypeAdding
        
        private var subjects: [UIControl.Event : Subject<Point>] = [:]
        fileprivate private(set) lazy var observers
            : [UIControl.Event : Observer<Point>] 
            = subjects.mapValues({ subject in subject.observer })
        
        public subscript(event: UIControl.Event) -> Observable<Point> {
            if subjects[event] == nil {
               subjects[event] = Subject<Point>()
               newEventTypeAdding.send(event)
            }
            
            return subjects[event]!
        }
    }
}
```

As we can see `ButtonEvents.observers` is the seed of the problem.

I can reimplement `observers` as Computed Property, but I will lose performence O(1) in dictionary items accessing.

Comment: Dictionaries are *value types*  in Swift. Modifying `origin` does not affect `adapted`.

Comment: If you tell us *why* you are trying to do this, we can help you figure out a solution that works for you.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez I added remark to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your last edit:

```
struct AdaptedDict<Key: Hashable, Value> {

    private var origin: UnsafeMutablePointer<[Key: Value]>
    private let transform: (Value) -> Value

    init(_ origin: inout [Key: Value], transform: @escaping (Value) -> Value) {
        self.origin = UnsafeMutablePointer(&origin)
        self.transform = transform
    }

    subscript(_ key: Key) -> Value? {
        if let value = origin.pointee[key] {
            return transform(value)
        }
        return nil
    }

}

var origin = ["A": 10, "B": 20]
var adaptedDict = AdaptedDict(&origin) { $0 * 2 }
print(origin["A"], adaptedDict["A"])
origin["A"] = 20
print(origin["A"], adaptedDict["A"])
```

So basically you store the dictionary using the pointer.

Comment: `print(adapted.pointee["C"])` printed 10, but I expected 20. I need an adapter to read. It should return double values of `origin` without `origin` changes.

Comment: I edited my question. Is it possible to use `&origin` in `DictionaryView` to have expected result?

Comment: @ValentineZakharenko check now

Comment: Keeping one more dictionary and syncing it with transformations is a good workable idea. But I can't catch: Why do you `mapValues` in `origin.didSet` instead of do `adapted[key] = transform(newValue)` in `subscript.set`? As for me, the first one has O(n), second - O(1). I don't understand something important about value and reference types in swift? Is it realy has no difference? (except code lines count)

Comment: I’ll write a better solution in 30 min, I don’t have my pc now

Comment: @ValentineZakharenko check now, tell me what you think

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because

> Dictionary are value types

What you should do here is use `Computed Property`

```
var adapted: [String: Int] {
    return origin.mapValues { $0 * 2 }
}
```

Now call it anywhere the result will be as expected

Comment: Thank you. It will work. But I worry about performance. The advantage of the dictionary is O(1). Computing of the new dictionary fully (when the client needs to access one item) will kill this advantage. I will add a remark to my question to describe more details about the real situation

Comment: How large this the dictionary, and what is the common pattern for accessing this? You can't discuss performance in abstract O(x) terms. It deeply matters the situation. O(1) does not mean "fast." O(1) can take dramatically longer than O(n) for a given n. There are ways, for example, to make this lazy, and that will be faster for some use patterns, but it will be *slower* for other use patterns. Write simply and clearly first.

Comment: @RobNapier Yes, you are right performance is depended to context. In my real situation, I have no a lot of items (max = 10). But I am trying to find how to adapt dictionary (without loss of O) over the concrete situation too (in abstract data structures level).

Comment: I used your answer as a solution. I have no a lot of items in my dictionary and your solution is acceptable for my real-world problem. But for me is interesting: How to solve this problem in case when the dictionary contains a lot of items?  I didn't point in my original question clearly that I need this adaptation only for reading.  Fixed. Sorry about that. @RobNapier, lazy? Dictionary hasn't lazy property like array.

Comment: @ValentineZakharenko You would need to build a LazyMapDictionary yourself (like the existing LazyMapSequence). It's buildable. When you say "has a lot of items," it also will matter how you plan to consume it. Will an accessor of the dictionary typically consume most of the items exactly once, or consume items multiple times, or consume only a small portion of the items? Will the underlying dictionary typically change in small ways or dramatically? Building a performant data structure for this is highly dependent on all of these.

Answer (score 1):

`Swift.Dictionary` has value semantics.  If you want reference semantics then Foundation has `NSMutableDictionary`.  You really shouldn't be afraid of `Swift.Dictionary` unless you have a genuine performance concern (ie you are mutating millions of records and you are sure its actually triggering copy on write).

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import Foundation

let d: NSMutableDictionary = [ "a": 1, "b": 2]
for (key, value) in d {
    guard let value = value as? Int else { continue}
    d[key] = value * 2
}
print(d)
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I didn't know that Dictionary is value type before this discussion. I am from C# Java world where Dictionary is a reference type.

Comment: So its actually *not* a value type.  It has *value semantics*.  That means its generally implemented as a reference, but with copy on write behavior so it behaves *as if* it were a reference except when you are writing to a copy.  This is also true of Swift.String and Swift.array and Swift.Set.

Answer (score 0):

As **Martin R** said if you modify the `origin` array after generating the `adapted` array won't affect it. So you first create the `origin`

```
var origin = ["A":2, "B":3]
```

then you modify it by adding `origin["C"] = 6` and then you can create the `adapted` array.

```
var adapted = origin.mapValues { $0 * 2 }
print(origin)
print(adapted)
```

this should give you the result you expect.

Comment: I need true adaptation, not just mapped copy of the state at the mapping moment.

Comment: Then Razi's answer is the correct one. You need the computed property.